# Accessing Infopath form over the internet

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010, workflowservice

We are a worldwide charitable organisation. We have a problem with one of our SharePoint applications and we are a bit desperate here due to the unavailability of solutions.

A description of the problem: Our SharePoint 2010 application uses Infopath 2010 for creating and submitting forms online to acquire approvals and authorisations. This system works perfectly within our intranet, but when we try to access this over the internet (we want it to be accessible both ways), it does not open up the InfoPath forms. We are using classic windows authentication.

What we have done is: Added the Alternate Access Mapping (https://sharepoint.xxx.org.uk) in the Internet zone of the Web Application, we have not added a binding in the IIS with https (could this be a problem?).

Then we are mapping the IP of this server to the UAG Forefront services to make it available over the internet. Now the application is available over the intranet and the internet. But the problem is that, over the internet, the forms do not open they go on LOADING forever, now when we remove the firewall settings, the forms open to an error message that THERE HAS BEEN AN ERROR WHILE LOADING THE FORM. A REQUIRED RESOURCE COULD NOT BE DOWNLOADED. TO TRY TO RESUME THE DOWNLOAD, REFRESH THE PAGE.

We have tried and exhausted almost all options on the internet in forums and blogs but to no avail.

Could someone help us with this? We are really desperate to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that it cannot resolve the location of the XSN file over the internet.

If you have the correct license then perhaps it is worth considering using the [InfoPath Forms Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262263%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to allow the forms to be edited directly in a web browser.

Unless you are doing something special, your existing form may work directly in Forms Services without change.

As your question is also about sharepoint you may want to consider cross posting this question on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).